# What's the difference between DHCP Disabled or Relay on an access point?

Tags: router, ip, dhcp, access-point

I am trying to turn my old router to an access point for the new router, I assigned an IP address in the range of the new one and when I went to disable DHCP there was another option which is Relay and when activated you have to fill a field "DHCP Server for IP Relay Agent". So my question is what's the difference between the two options? knowing that I tried to go with the relay option and I entered the DHCP Server as the new router and it worked, I got internet access and dynamic IPs.
what would be the difference if I checked the disabled option in terms of IP assigning, does the old router pick up the configuration by itself or I am viewing this topic the wrong way?.

[image: Router Settings]

and if I may ask does the "Direction" setting affect this operation? because it was set to none.

Comment: Enabled means, that the AP is the DHCP server and therefore will give IP addresses to the clients connected. Relay means, that something else on your network is the DHCP server, for instance, if you have another router. The Relay IP address is the other routers IP address. The AP will then relay the DHCP packets to the clients connected. Relay is typically used, when the other DHCP server is on another IP subnet on your network. When disabled the AP clients will only be able to get DHCP, if the other DHCP server is on the same subnet as the AP and the clients connected.

Comment: @user56700 ah! so if DHCP is disabled on the old router, connected clients through it will automatically discover the DHCP server that is the new router?

Comment: Did you read my updated comment?

Comment: @user56700 Yes i updated my comment

Comment: Yes the clients on your AP should automatically discover the DHCP server, that is placed in the same IP subnet, since DHCP offer is typically broadcast or unicast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **DHCP Enabled** - Dynamically IP address is released (allocated) for Users on
>   Network.
>
> **DHCP Disabled** - Automatic IP address allocation is disabled, Need to
>   provide manual and Static IP address for Users or host
>
> **DHCP relay** - If you want to release IP address for separated subnet then
>   you need to use DHCP Relay Agent. (In this situation Your DHCP Server is not same subnet which you want to release IP address)